# htaccess rewriterule index.html

Tags: .htaccess

I'm using a PHP framework which redirect all URL to the index.php file using the following rule:

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

However, I want to be able to use index.html IF ANY ONLY IF users hit the home page. For instance, if users hit http:// website.com it will render the index.html file. Any other URL will use index.php. Could someone help?

ThankS

Answer (score 0):

```
^/(.+)$
```

Matches everything but the root.

However, either way this rewrite strategy is questionable. Sending absolutely *everything* to PHP — including `robots.txt`, `favicon.ico`, `crossdomain.xml`, other random things a bot might speculatively request, and *all* the automated break-in attempts on odd paths that don't exist — is likely to hit performance hard.

(It's also a potential problem if the script doesn't reply 404 properly for non-existant paths: someone could use file-based domain authentication to take over Google Webmaster Tools for your account.)

I'd try to put some limitations on what kind of paths are allowed to match.

Comment: Not to mention, what about images? css and javascript files?

Comment: I would suspect some `-d` and `-f` conds before this rule.